# peek() method in Queue interface

Tags: java, scjp

From [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html):

> The remove() and poll() methods remove and return the head of the queue.
>
> The element() and peek() methods return, but do not remove, the head of the queue.

From the second point it says method `peek()` returns head element of queue then how come its not returning head element of queue in the following program?

```
public class PQ {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>();
    pq.add("carrot"); 
    pq.add("apple"); 
    pq.add("banana");
    System.out.println(pq.poll() + ":" + pq.peek()); // prints apple and banana rather than apple and apple
}
}
```

Once the first element(carrot) is removed, apple becomes the head of queue(according to FIFO in queue) so peek()method should return apple right?

Example2:

```
public class PQ {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>();
    pq.add("carrot"); 
    pq.add("apple"); 
    pq.add("banana");
    System.out.println(pq); // prints [apple, carrot, banana] -> it should be [apple, banana, carrot] right? if it is following natural sorting order
}
}
```

Comment: `PriorityQueue` sorts the elements, meaning that the order of your queue is (head)`apple`, `banana`, `carrot`(tail).  Thus, the call to `poll()` removes and returns the head (`apple`), making `banana` the new head, as seen in the following call to `peek()`.

Comment: so `PriorityQueue` doesn't follow FIFO?

Comment: Elements are stored in order and then it's FIFO. In order is not the order in which it is inserted but the priority order.

Comment: @kittu Correct; it follows natural ordering instead.

Comment: @Vulcan please look at the example 2 in updated question

Comment: @Vulcan Does natural sorting order means lexicographical order in case of comparing in `PriorityQueue`

Comment: yes natural sorting order `lexicographical ` ordering in case of Strings.

Comment: Tom: Please try out the code sample(example2) from the question. Its printing "a", "c", "b" which is not right order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are polling first

```
System.out.println(pq.poll() + ":" + pq.peek());
```

As it is a priority queue elements are stored as

```
carrot -> banana -> apple
```

When you `poll()` you get `apple` and is removed from queue. After which head of queue is `banana` which is exactly what you get when you `peek()`.

> please look at the example 2 in updated question. Sorting is strange

It's just what you don't expect. You can see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

You will understand this better if you read priority heap data structure which java priority queue use. You should use `poll(), peek()` methods to get ordered data.

Comment: Thankur: Refer to Balaji Katika answer above, I am confused between yours and his answer in regards to sorting of elements

Comment: By default it takes natural ordering. If you don't want that you can pass your own comparator in the constructor `public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity,Comparator<? super E> comparator)`

Comment: If you don't supply a comparator then natural ordering is used. And for a class to be able to naturally order itself it should implement `Comparable` interface. Since you are using String and String implements `Comparable` you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: What I am trying to ask is: are the elements are stored as `carrot -> banana -> apple` or `apple -> banana -> carrot` ? as it is a PriorityQueue?

Comment: `apple` will be the 0th index of your queue. So if you think of a typical queue `apple` will be the head , `banana` after that and `carrot` there after.

Comment: please look at the example 2 in updated question. Sorting is strange

Comment: Thankur: Thankyou so much for answering my question with patience

Answer (score 2):

You are using PriorityQueue and not java.util.Queue (Regular Queue)
PriorityQueue sorts the elements depending on the implementation of the Comparable::compareTo() method which is a natural ordering (alphabetical order) for String.class.

Hence, the elements in your queue would be apple-banana-carrot. 
The output is as expected

Answer (score 2):

You have answered the question yourself by quoting the documentation.

Your priority queue contains

```
apple, banana, carrot
```

`poll` returns "apple" then removes it. So the queue is now

```
banana, carrot
```

`peek` then returns "banana"

Answer (score 2):

POLL() method will remove that element from queue and return element to calling method.
PEEK() method will only return that element.
refer this implementation code of POLL() and PEEK() method:

```
public E poll() {
        if (this.size == 0)
            return null;
        int i = --this.size;
        this.modCount += 1;
        Object localObject1 = this.queue[0];
        Object localObject2 = this.queue[i];
        this.queue[i] = null; 
        if (i != 0)
            siftDown(0, localObject2);
        return localObject1;
}

public E peek() {
        return ((this.size == 0) ? null : this.queue[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Queue interface defines some methods for acting on the first element of the list, which differ in the way they behave. These methods are:

```
peek()
element()
poll()
remove()
```

**The peek()** This method retrieves the value of the first element of the queue without removing it from the queue. For each invocation of the method we always get the same value and its execution does not affect the size of the queue. If the queue is empty the peek() method returns null.

**The element()** This method behaves like peek(), so it again retrieves the value of the first element without removing it. Unlike peek ), however, if the list is empty element() throws a NoSuchElementException.

**The poll()** This method retrieves the value of the first element of the queue by removing it from the queue. . At each invocation it removes the first element of the list and if the list is already empty it returns null but does not throw any exception.

**The remove()** This method behaves as the poll() method, so it removes the first element of the list and if the list is empty it throws a NoSuchElementException